# Как получить выборку с группировкой и кол-вом общих записей

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица:

```
+-----+-------+
|  id | team  |
+-----+-------+
| 1   | 1     |
| 2   | 2     |
| 3   | 2     |
| 4   | 3     |
+-----+-------+
```

Мне нужно получить из этой таблицы всех пользователей и посчитать сколько в их команде пользователей всего.

```
SELECT id, count(team), team FROM user_team GROUP BY id
```

Как и положено возвращает что у одного пользователя одна команда.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY team) users_in_team
FROM user_team;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6bba22a8218430da25f50b9da985aaa2)

Answer (score 1):

группировать надо по team, ф потом подзапрос объединять с основным по номеру команды

```
select id, cnt 
  from user_team 
     join 
       (SELECT team, count(id) cnt 
          FROM user_team 
          GROUP BY team
        ) t using(team)
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d94966/2)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю правильно сделал или нет, но ничего умнее не придумал кроме как это:

```
SELECT id, team,  COUNT(DISTINCT ut2.user) FROM user_team ut
LEFT JOIN user_team ut2 ON ut.team = ut2.team
GROUP BY id
```